# Get client readonly property on server side?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I'm using jQuery to toggle the `readonly` property on .NET TextBoxes both on JavaScript pageLoad() and dynamically through events.

I can see this property is added correctly to the textbox HTML, for instance:

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="txtSalesYear1" 
    onkeypress="return IsNumberKey(event, true);" data-control-id="sales-textbox" 
    data-relative-year="1" data-region-id="1" data-subregion-id="2" 
    data-year="2014" readonly>
```

However, when I check on the server side postback, the `readonly` attribute is null:

```
txtSalesYear1.Attributes.Item("readonly")  ' = Nothing
```

When I loop through the Attributes collection, I see all the other custom attributes and their correct values.  How can I obtain this readonly property?

Comment: Browser doesn't send such data with form submit. It sends just values of input\textarea controls inside the form. It won't send any attributes except values

Comment: Like the above comment, the readonly attribute is not sent to the server. You'll have to store the change somewhere else like a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

The readonly attribute may be "readonly =  "readonly" or "" (empty string) or empty". Try setting attribute to readonly="readonly" and then look at the postback attribute.

Assuming that you are providing the output of a .NET textbox (as this was marked as a webform) and not a standard HTML textbox, you would add the tag like such:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the rendered source would look like:

```
 <input name="TextBox1" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="TextBox1" />
```

Then serverside

C#

```
var isReadonly = ((TextBox)TextBox1).ReadOnly;
```

VB.NET

```
Dim isReadonly = DirectCast(TextBox1, TextBox).[ReadOnly]
```

And there is your value for the control's read only attribute.